# Getting error when compiled Http webrequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

i have written a program to search value from google every thing works fine but first time when page is loaded then i encounter error.after words if i click any link it is working fine no errors further.

[image]

Code is as follow

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string raw = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q={0}&aq=f&oq=&aqi=n1g10";
            string search = string.Format(raw, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(searchTerm));
            //string search = "http://www.whatismyip.com/";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(search);

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
                {
                    browserA = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(IE1));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error didn't come from Http webrequest,it's from the web browser control on your form.
It's a javascript error raised by web browser control,you can suppress it by:

`webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Disable Internet Explorer notification for script errors
see http://www.tech-faq.com/internet-explorer-script-error.html